# Only 1 data submitted into database (food ordering system)

Tags: php, ajax

I am new on implementing Ajax on PHP so I need a big help! anyways my problem is I have a 5 column names on my table_menu

table_menu:

> menu_id
>   menu_foodname
>   menu_price
>   menu_quantity
>   menu_image

and inside those column names it has 6 datas.

And I will gonna fetch those datas on my webpage(users.php)

```
<?php 
        // users.php
        // fetching data
        include 'config/initialize.php'; 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_menu"; 
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if($res)
        {
        echo "<table><tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {

            echo "<td>";
            echo "<div class='horizontalAlign'>";
            echo "<form class='form-item' method='post'>";
            echo "<img class='img-circle' src='menuImage/".$row['menu_image']."' style='height: 150px; width: 200px;'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='menuimage' class='menuimage' value='".$row['menu_image']."'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='menufoodname' class='menufoodname' value='".$row['menu_foodname']."' style='border:none; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 30px; font-size: 20px;' readonly>";
            echo "<div style='font-size: 20px; margin-left: 40px;'>Price:</div> <input type='text' class='menuprice' name='menuprice' value='".$row['menu_price']."' style='border:none; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: -28px; position: absolute; font-size: 20px;' readonly>";
            echo "<div style='font-size: 20px;'>Quantity:</div> <input type='number' class='menuquantity' name='menuquantity' style='margin-top: -26px; position: absolute; margin-left: 90px; text-align: center;' value='".$row['menu_quantity']."' min='0' max='100'>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<input type='button' value='Submit order' class='btnaddorder btn btn-lg btn-info' class='btn btn-info'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</td>";
            $i++;

                if($i == 3)
                {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                }

        } // end of while

                echo "</tr></table>";

        } // end of variable $i

        ?> <!-- // end of fetching data -->
```

and I want the page to be not refresh while the user orders... so I add this ajax script on the bottom of users.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btnaddorder").click(function() {
        var menuimage = $(".menuimage").val();
        var menufoodname = $(".menufoodname").val();
        var menuprice = $(".menuprice").val();
        var menuquantity = $(".menuquantity").val();

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("addorders.php", {
            menuimage1: menuimage,
            menufoodname1: menufoodname,
            menuprice1: menuprice,
            menuquantity1: menuquantity,
            }, function(data) {

                });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Now the problem is when I am clicking the first button on the fetched datas the first one only got inserted and if I am add the second item even the third until fifth item it only display one data on the database which is the first data, why?

heres my addorders.php

```
<?php 

    include 'config/initialize.php';
    include 'credentials/credentialsForUsers.php';

    $menuimage = $_POST['menuimage1'];
    $menufoodname = $_POST['menufoodname1'];
    $menuprice = $_POST['menuprice1'];
    $menuquantity = $_POST['menuquantity1'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_orders VALUES('','$username','$email','$menuimage','$menufoodname','$menuprice','$menuquantity')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


?>
```

thank you & sorry for my bad english. hope you understand my problem

Comment: Because __how__ can js understand which of `.menuimage` items do you need?

Comment: @u_mulder yes that's why how can I tell js to dynamically stored desired data into the database

Comment: your aproach is wrong, increase the number for each input as in menufoodname_1 menufoodname_2 etc, also suspect the reason only the first product gets submitted is you have multiple forms with the same input names

Answer (score 0):

To clarify which fields you want to submit you can do the following:

```
$(".btnaddorder").click(function() {
    // here you find closest form tag to the pressed button
    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    // replace all you values with simple .serialize() function
    // this function will use all non-disable fields from the form
    $.post("addorders.php", form.serialize(), function(data) { });
});
```

On the serverside your `$_POST` will have the same keys as fields on your form.

Comment: thank you for the response but I tried the serialize function recently and it didn't worked. please helpp

Comment: Did you __try__ my code? If yes - what errors do you see in developers console or any unexpected behaviour?

Comment: yes Sir, and it says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest is not a function"

Comment: What's your jquery version?

Comment: 3-3-1 minified js and 3-3-7 minified js Sir.

Comment: Try to use `var form = $(this).parent();`, according to your markup it is the form.

Comment: it works Sir, but if I click the first button the second data on my table_menu will inserted while if I clicked on the rest(button) there's no data inserted I mean only the column id has a data the rest is blank..

Comment: php code for insertion? yes Sir, I changed the $_post as same name on my fetched form

Comment: Okay, enough. Data is passed to server, now do a debug, check what fields you have in `$_POST`, check your php-code again. If something is wrong - ask another question.